# How to show network data in Gridview

Tags: api, flutter, dart, gridview

I have a `GridView` and I was able to show data from a static list. Now, I want to show the data from an api, I know it can be done by using `FutureBuilder` but I don't know how to do it.

This is my api call:

```
  Future<Map> getJson() async {

  String apiUrl = 'http://3.127.255.230/rest_ci/api/products/show_all_prod?rest_id=6';

Map<String,String> headers = {
  http.Response response = await http
   .get(apiUrl);


  return json.decode(response.body); // returns a List type
}


void dataShower() async{
  getJson();
    Map _data = await getJson();
    print(_data);
}
```

Here is my `GridView` with a local list of food:

```
     GridView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              primary: false,
              physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                crossAxisCount: 2,
                childAspectRatio: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width /
                    (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 1.25),
              ),
              itemCount: foods == null ? 0 :foods.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
//                Food food = Food.fromJson(foods[index]);
                Map food = foods[index];
//                print(foods);
//                print(foods.length);
                return GridProduct(
                  img: food['img'],
                  isFav: false,
                  name: food['name'],
                  rating: 5.0,
                  raters: 23,
                );
              },
            ),
```

This is my api response:

```
{
    "status": "SUCCESS",
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "name": "Fruit Salad",
            "slug": "fruit-salad",
            "description": "Nulla quis lorem ut libero malesuada feugiat. Lorem ips sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur aliquet quamid dui posuereblandit. Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Donec velit neque, auctor sit amet aliquam vel, ullamcorper sit amet ligula. Donec rutrum congue leo eget malesuada. Vivamus magna justo,",
            "unit_price": "50",
            "sale_unit_price": "0",
            "rest_id": "1",
            "cat_id": "4",
            "icon": "http://3.127.255.230/rest_ci/assets/uploads/products/1589784733__food12.jpg",
            "added_date": "2020-05-18 06:52:13",
            "updated_date": "2020-05-18 06:52:13",
            "status": "1"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "name": "Steak",
            "slug": "steak",
            "description": "this is just dummy description for all the products.\r\nthis is just dummy 
                        for all the products.\r\nthis is just dummy description for all the products.",
            "unit_price": "34",
            "sale_unit_price": "0",
            "rest_id": "1",
            "cat_id": "3",
            "icon": "http://3.127.255.230/rest_ci/assets/uploads/products/1589784928__food12.jpg",
            "added_date": "2020-05-18 06:55:28",
            "updated_date": "2020-05-18 06:55:28",
            "status": "1"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to add the result of that api call to the `GridView` (just name and icon) now it is populated on static list ,any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first convert json data to dart Model

```
class List {
  String status;
  List<Data> data;

  List({this.status, this.data});

  List.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    status = json['status'];
    if (json['data'] != null) {
      data = new List<Data>();
      json['data'].forEach((v) {
        data.add(new Data.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['status'] = this.status;
    if (this.data != null) {
      data['data'] = this.data.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Data {
  String id;
  String name;
  String slug;
  String description;
  String unitPrice;
  String saleUnitPrice;
  String restId;
  String catId;
  String icon;
  String addedDate;
  String updatedDate;
  String status;

  Data(
      {this.id,
      this.name,
      this.slug,
      this.description,
      this.unitPrice,
      this.saleUnitPrice,
      this.restId,
      this.catId,
      this.icon,
      this.addedDate,
      this.updatedDate,
      this.status});

  Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    name = json['name'];
    slug = json['slug'];
    description = json['description'];
    unitPrice = json['unit_price'];
    saleUnitPrice = json['sale_unit_price'];
    restId = json['rest_id'];
    catId = json['cat_id'];
    icon = json['icon'];
    addedDate = json['added_date'];
    updatedDate = json['updated_date'];
    status = json['status'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['name'] = this.name;
    data['slug'] = this.slug;
    data['description'] = this.description;
    data['unit_price'] = this.unitPrice;
    data['sale_unit_price'] = this.saleUnitPrice;
    data['rest_id'] = this.restId;
    data['cat_id'] = this.catId;
    data['icon'] = this.icon;
    data['added_date'] = this.addedDate;
    data['updated_date'] = this.updatedDate;
    data['status'] = this.status;
    return data;
  }
}
```

and change `Future<Map> getJson() async` to `List getJson() async`
in getJsone return List.fromJson(json.decode(response.body))

then you can use this list like a static list

Answer (score 0):

use FutureBuilder (https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data)
to show data from a future mothod like getJson()

and in getJson(), convert json data to a dart class model

Comment: i  already used future builder with listview.builder but i don't know how to do it with gridview